# Google Analytics enhanced ecommerce not tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I have been tormented with this problem for several days, dont know whats the deal.
I have this code on the product page:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
ga('require', 'ec');

ga('ec:addProduct', {
 'id': '145645',
 'name': 'BlaBlaBla',
 'category': 'BlaBlaBla',
 'brand': 'BlaBlaBla',
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'detail', { 'step': 1 });
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

GA debugger plugin output indicates that everything is OK:

```
Running command: ga("require", "ec")
Running command: ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "145645", name: "BlaBlaBla", category: "BlaBlaBla", brand: "BlaBlaBla"})
Running command: ga("ec:setAction", "detail", {step: 1})
Running command: ga("send", "pageview")
```

But no data is seen on the GA page!

The enhanced ecommerce plugin for now is performing only on the products pages for the reason of testing. IP filter is off, all script and adblockers disabled. 
I think my problem is lying on the top, just can`t figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**
On the purchase page Enhanced e-commerce is working, I see the data on GA page!

```
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1');
    ga('require', 'ec');
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': '137883',
        'name': "BlaBlaBla",
        'price': 2790.00,
        'quantity': 1
    });
    ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
        'id': '1595',
        'revenue': 2790.00,
    });
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Do you have enhanced ecommerce enabled within the views?

Comment: Where can I enable it? On GA->Admin->E-commerce settings page I see only: Enable E-commerce
Edit
Status: ON
Related Products: OFF; Enable Enhanced E-commerce Reporting ON.

Answer (score 0):

The {step:1} is intended to be used in the checkout action and you're using it in the detail one.

From [enhanced ecommerce tracking documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce):

> step (Number):    A number representing a step in the checkout process.
>   Optional on checkout actions.

I would remove the third parameter changing:

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'detail', { 'step': 1 });
```

by

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');
```